# Set View Attributes for ListView Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I've been trying to override `getView()` in the adapter for a listview to set attributes for views within the layout:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guest_list_row, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.GuestName);
    Button RSVPIndicator = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.RSVPState);

    Invites invite = data.get(position);

    name.setText(nameContact(invite.getUserID()));
    int RSVPState = invite.getAttending();

    if (RSVPState == 1) {
        RSVPIndicator.setBackgroundColor(color.GuestAccepted);

    }
    if (RSVPState == 0) {
        RSVPIndicator.setBackgroundColor(color.GuestDeclined);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

Unfortunately the set methods I am calling on the view components seem to do nothing. The background color does change for the RSVPIndicator however not the color I have specified.

I've tried a lot of different values to set the views with no luck. Is there something trivial I am missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You checked the value of `RSVPState` to be sure you get 0 or 1?

Comment: Yep, because it does change the colour of some rows but not to the colour specified, seems to be a default grey...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this instead:

```
if (RSVPState == 1) {
    RSVPIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.color.GuestAccepted);
}
else if (RSVPState == 0) {
    RSVPIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.color.GuestDeclined);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, works a treat thanks! What are the differences in the techniques?

Comment: Actually the one you used first is expecting the numeric form of a color, for example `0xff000000` for black. But the one I suggested is getting a color resource defined in the system.